# WPF contextMenu click issue

Tags: wpf

A `ListBox` and a `ContextMenu` are created dynamicaly. The `ListBox` has some items. 
How do I know the `ListBoxItem` `Text` that right mouse button  clicked on?

```
private void Init2()
{ 
    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

    MenuItem menuItemOpen = new MenuItem();
    menuItemOpen.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(menuItemOpen_Click);
    contextMenu.Items.Add(menuItemOpen);
    listBox1.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
}
void menuItemOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //How do I know the listItem text that  right mouse button clicked on?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you right click, you actually also select. So that means you can just do:

```
    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedListBoxItemText = ((ListBoxItem)listBox1.SelectedItem).Content.ToString());

        // do your thing
    }
```

Comment: How does it help me to know the text of ListBoxItem?